# TBB task_group hang when using concurrent_hash_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I am attempting to use a tbb::concurrent_hash_map within a running task, but I'm running into the issue that calling the map's erase() causes the task to lock infinitely. Any ideas what could be wrong with the snippet below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h>
#include <tbb/task_group.h>
#include <tbb/task_scheduler_init.h>

class BusyTask
{
public:    
    void operator()() {

        typedef tbb::concurrent_hash_map<unsigned int, int> MyMap;
        MyMap m;
        MyMap::accessor a;
        m.insert(a, 1);
        m.erase(1); // The task will lock up at this point

    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Started" << std::endl;

    BusyTask busyTask1;

    tbb::task_group taskGroup;
    taskGroup.run(busyTask1);
    taskGroup.wait();

    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm testing with TBB v4.0.5, and GCC 4.7

Comment: try scoping the accessor, e.g.:
        { MyMap::accessor; m.insert(a, 1); }
        m.erase(1); // The task will lock up at this poin

Comment: Perfect, that works. Thanks!
I should have read the "accessor" documentation a little more closely: [concurrent access](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls/concurrent_access.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As correctly noted in the comment, it's the problem of the locking scope. `erase(1)` needs to acquire the same lock which is already acquired by insert() operation (and the locks are not recursive).

Please also pay attention to erase(by_accessor) method of the hash map which guarantees that exactly the element protected by the accessor will be erased and not another element with the same key. The later can happen if concurrent threads erased it (providing the same key) and added new element with the same key.